# A first-order ODE solvable in a case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The ODE

$$y'+\left(-1+\frac{a-1}{x}\right)y+b x -c=0$$

is solved by $y=bx$ in the particular case $c=ab$.

How would you proceed to find a more general solution?

Comment: This seems solvable with an [Integrating Factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $$y'+\left(-1+\frac{a-1}{x}\right)y+b x -c=0$$ is linear.

You have $$y= y_h + y_p$$ where $y_h$ is the solution to the homogeneous equation, $$y'+\left(-1+\frac{a-1}{x}\right)y=0$$ and $:y_p $. is a particular solution to the in-homogeneous equation.

Both solutions are found easily because for the first one the equation is separable and for the second one you may use variation of constant.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple, the solutions can be expressed with the help of [Whittaker functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function):

[image]

Comment: I think that the solution is much simpler.

Comment: Maybe, but Maple cannot simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this equation can be put in the form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$, you can solve by using the integrating factor $e^{\int a(x)\operatorname dx}$.